# UITableViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize adds extra 0.5 px

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have cell with only one button in it, I've added height of button = 30, top = 10 and bottom = 10 constraints, so systemLayoutSizeFittingSize must return height of cell = 50. Nevertheless it returns 50.5 and I see in the log :

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

I'm using grouped table view and separator set to none. Where it takes extra 0.5px?

[image: constraints]

code snippet:

```
[cell layoutSubviews];
return [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;// 50;
```

log:

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa71e273e0 V:[UIButton:0x7ffa71e24900'Book a new hotel'(30)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa71e20bc0 V:|-(10)-[UIButton:0x7ffa71e24900'Book a new hotel']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa71e06030 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa71e23ae0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa71e06030.bottomMargin == UIButton:0x7ffa71e24900'Book a new hotel'.bottom + 2>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa705f6640 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa71e06030(50.5)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa71e273e0 V:[UIButton:0x7ffa71e24900'Book a new hotel'(30)]>
```

Comment: Please can you show the entire error log. It will show what is happening.

Comment: Is your target iOS8?

Comment: 7+ i know there is brilliant solution for cell height in 8.. but we need 7.

Comment: I think it should have been `[cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1;`

Comment: you are right it should be cell.contentView, instead of cell. And there is no need to add "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**iOS 8**

If your target is iOS8 then it makes this much easier as table view cells can now be sized automagically by AutoLayout.

To do this just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in your `heightForRow` method...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Essentially this does what I think you are trying to do with your code snippet.

**iOS 7**

For iOS 7 I'd set out the constraints differently. Instead of setting the top and bottom constraints I'd just have a "centre vertically" constraint.

Then you can return any number you want to return and the constraints won't break.

You don't get the automatic height thing but the height doesn't appear to change anyway.

Comment: i'm targeting 7. thanks for pointing me the fact that it will not change anyway. but it's really interesting, where it takes extra 0.5

Comment: @trickster77777 Yeah, AutoLayout can be odd sometimes and I've seen things like this myself. I guess it's because it can't place stuff at 0.5 pixels or something. Not sure why it would need to though?

Comment: If I remember well that 0.5 is the cell separator size and is always added to the cell height.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoSantangeli